# how to close a dialog box in batch file by clicking OK

Tags: batch-file, dialog

I have a batch script which runs a command:

```
certreq -submit -attrib "CertificateTemplate:WebServer" CSR.csr CRT.crt
```

This produces a dialog box to named as "Select Certificate Authority" with OK and cancel button, I need to proceed with OK to complete that command. Can I do it with command to close the box by processing it with OK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used autoit tool to get it done. It is simple to use.
Below are the autoit commands.

```
WinWaitActive("Certification Authority List")
WinWaitActive("Certification Authority List")
ControlClick("Certification Authority List","OK","[CLASS:Button; INSTANCE:1]")
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try with [**sendkeys.bat**](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/sendKeys.bat):

```
call sendkeys.bat "certificate" "{enter}"
```

The first argument is the title of the window you want to process and the second is the string you want to send to it.[Here you can](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c6yea83(v=vs.84).aspx) find an info what special characters you can send.